# Django 2.2 img's not loading

Tags: python, django, image, file

I'm actually new to django and I found a problem when loading my images, I did the settings like the docs said and it saves my images to the right folder. Just the loading part does not work as I want it to.

```
# the settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# the Model
class Legend(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        published = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery', blank=True, null=True)

# the template where i use the img field
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <img style="width: 245px; height: 247px;" src="{{ instance.image.url }}" alt="legend image"">    
{% endfor %}
```

the upload is working as expected. Saves all images to the media folder (which is on the applevel)
so: media/gallery/name.jpg.
running the server doesnt show the image but the source seems fine:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/gallery/gto.jpg

There seems to be a problem with serving files locally when debugging, but all i could find were for older django versions. Iam using django --version 2.2.

I appreciaty any help

Comment: Are you setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` in settings.py?

Comment: did you add ```+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)``` in your urls.py?

Comment: no i don't set STATICFILES_DIRS, why is that needed? isnt django looking for the media_root and media strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are running django under `DEBUG = True`, you should also add media urls:

Add this to end of your main `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    # and this one to serve static files:
    #urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. But i dont understand why thats necessary? And in production do i have to do smth similar to get the images to serve when deployed?

Comment: @Amnesie In development, because you are using django's minimal server, you need to add this in order for your user-uploaded files to be served. But there is no need for this in production as your web-server will take care of those. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: Also, from django 2.1, you no longer need that `if settings.DEBUG` because django will check that automatically.

Comment: @Amnesie Please also mark the answer as accepted so that other people can reference it later.